# Showing that if a curve $F$ of degree $n$ has a point of multiplicity $n$ then $F$ consists of $n$ lines through that point.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is **question 3.3 from Fulton's Algebraic Curves**. The question is:

*Show that if a curve $F$ of degree $n$ has a point $P$ of multiplicity $n$ then $F$ consists of $n$ lines through $P$ (not necessarily distinct).*

I can only show the converse so far:

If $F$ consists of $n$ lines through $P$ (not necessarily distinct) then we can write $$F=\prod_{i=1}^n L_i,$$
with $L_i$ a line through $P$ for each $i$, and with the $L_i$'s not necessarily distinct.

Then $$m_P(F)=m_P\left(\prod_{i=1}^n L_i\right) =\sum_{i=1}^nm_P(L_i),$$
where $m_P(F)$ denotes the multiplicity of $P$ on $F$.

Because $L_i$ is a line and $P\in L_i$, then $m_P(L_i)=1$ for any $i$.

So $$m_P(F)=n.$$

I don't see any way to reverse engineer this to show the desired statement. I have a way to show it which uses that each irreducible component of $F$ is a cubic, but the question at hand is more general than that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** If the curve is in one variable $X$, then I can write $F=(X-P)^n$, and then the result is immediate. Analogously, if the curve is in $X_1,...,X_n$ then I can write $F=(X_n-P)(X_{n-1}-P)\cdots (X_1-P)$ and the result is immediate. But then I am assuming that $F$ is reducible. How would the irreducible case look?

Comment: Unless one knows Fulton's book (which I don't), it's impossible to know what tools you have available to use. Do you know the tangent cone to $F$ at the point $p$? (Does Fulton actually do what you've done several times, using the same letter for the curve and for its defining polynomial? I  hope not.)

Comment: No, the tangent cone to $F$ at a point is not covered in his book. And he indeed uses the same letter for the curve and for its defining polynomial. In fact he only mentions the phrase "defining polynomial" once, to say "The degree of a curve is the degree of a defining polynomial for the curve", but that term does not appear anywhere else in the text. Which text in algebraic geometry would you recommend? I have also used Gathmann, but because there are so many other texts, I have yet to pick one new one to look at. A new text = a new set of notation! So, I am reluctant to make the switch.

Comment: A definition of "point of multiplicity $n$" and "curve of degree $n$" may make the result obvious.

Comment: Do you mean what I added in the "Edit" part of the question?

Comment: I do not know whether you have done intersection multiplicities. If $C$ is a curve and $P$ is a point on $C$, for any line $L$ through $P$, you have $(L\cdot C)\geq m_P(C)$ and there are only finitely many $L$ where this is a strict inequality.